# Strategy for deploying Panels with features

Tags: panels, features

I've been exporting Panelizer configuration to features and pushing up to production.  My strategy so far has been:

- Config is created on local and pushed up via features
- Content, such as Fieldable Panels Panes instances are created directly on production.

However, this is now causing issues.  When I revert a Panel/Panelizer feature, it reverts back to my local settings and removes any content panes I've added on production.

A couple of ideas I have for managing content panes:

- Use UUID features to push up any content panes.  Trouble with this is that the content panes are now in the dev/stage/live workflow and any changes on production will be reverted with the next `drush fra`.
- Pull down a fresh copy of the database before doing any further edits to a feature, that way when a feature is recreated on local, it will contain the new content panes.

How do you manage content panes when using features?

Answer (score 1):

We have very similar problems - not only with features but in other areas as well. The best solution we came up with so far is close to your second one:

Drupal 6 & 7 - Yin/Yang Multisite Staging
https://www.drupal.org/node/942540

So here you'd switch with the new DB version into the Staging system and use the Staging as the new Live version. But I don't feel too comfortable about this + it might not work everywhere if the two Servers are different.

In a way less complex evironment with small changes I'm doing the following: Every night the DB will be copied from Live to Dev. In this environment I'm sure I only have small changes in Dev which take usually minutes to an hour max. and I've got a fresh DB every day and can start from there.

Comment: Thanks. The site is hosted on platform.sh, so it handles the merging/syncing between environments really well. For the most part my workflow is quite smooth - but when content and configuration crossover, like in the case of content panes, things get tricky.